# After Importing Products, Products are not editable and also not visible

Tags: magento-1.9, import, dataflow

its me again. My question was not solved yesterday after working a lot of hours figuring it out i could import products without errors. But the new error now is, those imported products are shown under it's subcategory but i can't access it and in the frontend it shows only for the category how much products are in there but none is visible.

Backend View:
[image: Admin Backend in the Categorysection:]

Frontend View:
[image: Category in the Frontend:]

Import without error:

[image: Import without error:]

In the Backend under Manage Products there is no product of the imported ones visible.
What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. I took the link of a not shown product guided by this:

If your products are showing in the database, so try to do the following:

Go to catalog -> manage products. Your current url will look like:

[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[your_key]/

Change this url to [yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[your_key]/

You can find the product ids in the database. When you enter this url, you can edit the product and check/edit product attributes, like tax class, status, etc.
After that you can check which values are not filled and in this way you can clearly see all little mistakes by the Values in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of this problem seems to be the language of the import file data.

If you try to import an `italian/french/german` etc data in a fresh Magento installation `(in english by default)` some parameters doesn't match.

So, for example, the attribute 'status' is not assigned in products relationships and the products won't be visible in backend product list.

The fastest solution is to install the desired language package from magentocommerce, set the correct language in magento and re-import the data in magento.